# Cors Policy doesn't take my specified Methods Express Gateway

Tags: angular, express, methods, cors, gateway

I have an app in angular and i use express gateway to have some control in my petitions on the backEnd side, everything works fine except of my Cors Methods, i just want to allow GET,PUT,POST but even when i don't put DELETE method it still can access, i don't know where i'm wrong, i already read the documentation.

```
{
"http": {
    "port": 8080,
},
"admin": {
    "port": 9876,
    "host": "localhost"
},
"apiEndpoints": {
    "apiAngular": {
        "host": "13.84.42.7",
        "paths": "/api/v3/*"
    },
    "api": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "paths": "/ip"
    }
},
"serviceEndpoints": {
    "service_apiAngular": {
        "url": "http://localhost:4002"
    },
    "httpbin": {
        "url": "https://httpbin.org"
    }
},
"policies": [
    "cors",
    "basic-auth",
    "expression",
    "key-auth",
    "log",
    "oauth2",
    "proxy",
    "rate-limit",
    "jwt"
],
"pipelines": {
    "pipeline_apiAngular": {
        "apiEndpoints": [
            "apiAngular"
        ],
        "policies": [
            {
                "cors":{
                    [
                        "action":{
                            "origin": "*",
                            "methods": "GET,PUT,POST",
                            "preflightContinue": false,
                            "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
                        }
                    ]

                }
            },
            {
                "rate-limit": [
                    {
                        "action": {
                            "max": 15,
                            "windowMs": 1200
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "proxy": [
                    {
                        "action": {
                            "serviceEndpoint": "service_apiAngular"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
        "apiEndpoints": [
            "api"
        ],
        "policies": [
            {
                "proxy": [
                    {
                        "action": {
                            "serviceEndpoint": "httpbin",
                            "changeOrigin": true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMethodNotFound

Use Access-Control-Allow-Methods to allow the http requests methods you want to allow

Comment: But i still want to use Express Gateway, and manage the Access-Control-Allow-Methods there.